# ValueError: Only TF native optimizers are supported in Eager mode

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I applied Eager execution to my code using

```
import TensorFlow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
tf.executing_eagerly()
```

But when I used Adam Optimizer

```
single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,
                                           input_shape=x_train.shape[-2:]))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

single_step_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mae')
```

I got the error as

```
ValueError: Only TF native optimizers are supported in Eager mode
```

Please help me guys

Comment: what is the error?. I cant't see it

Comment: Vote to close as this question seems more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use tf.train optimizer, and not tf.keras.* optimizer. Eg.:

````
single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,
                                           input_shape=x_train.shape[-2:]))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

single_step_model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss='mae')
```
````